# Get data from object

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

```
var obj={};
$('.nav ul li a').click( function() {
    var url=$(this).attr('href');
    var key=$(this).text();
    $('.cnt').load(url +' div', function() {
      obj[key]=$(this).html();
    });  

    if($('.cnt').html()==obj[key]) {
      //get it from obj not server
    }
});
```

How can i make on every next click after the first one to get the data from the object i've created not the server

Answer (score 0):

```
if(key in obj){
    //key property exist on object, do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `obj[key]` already exists

```
var obj = {};

$('.nav ul li a').click(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    var key = $(this).text();

    if(obj[key] == 'undefined') {
        /* get it from server*/
        $('.cnt').load(url + ' div', function(response) {    
            obj[key] = $(this).html();    
        });
    }else{
        /* already have data, put in elment*/
         $('.cnt').html( obj[key])
     }



});
```

Comment: it cant load if obj[key]==undefined

Comment: i have to load first and then check cause right now how can i tell if the data exist or not if i havent loaded anything

Comment: code I gave you does that. It checks if the data exists, if it doesn't it makes AJAX call to get it

Comment: if it doesnt exist i have to push it in the object and get it from there cause right now i click on the pages and i dont get any data cause it cant find it

Answer (score -1):

can you try this `obj.key = $(this).html()`